# aptitude unmarkauto trying to remove packages

Tags: aptitude

`aptitude unmarkauto` seems to have behaved strangely for me.  I had numerous packages that `apt-get autoremove` wanted to remove:

```
# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot ant ant-optional argyll at-spi2-core baobab browser-plugin-gnash
  caribou caribou-antler cheese dconf-tools empathy empathy-common espeak-data
  file-roller fonts-cantarell gcalctool gcr gdebi gdm3 gedit gedit-common
  gedit-plugins gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-tracker-0.14
  gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 glchess glines gnash gnash-common gnect
  gnibbles gnobots2 gnome-backgrounds gnome-color-manager gnome-dictionary
  gnome-disk-utility gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-games
  gnome-games-data gnome-games-extra-data gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-mag
  gnome-nettool gnome-orca gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data
  gnome-screenshot gnome-shell-extensions gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log
  gnome-tweak-tool gnome-video-effects gnomine gnotravex gnotski gnuchess
  gnuchess-book grilo-plugins-0.1 gtali gucharmap guile-2.0-libs
  hamster-applet hyphen-en-us iagno inkscape iputils-tracepath
  libapache-pom-java libatk-adaptor libatk-adaptor-data libatk-bridge2.0-0
  libatspi1.0-0 libatspi2.0-0 libavahi-gobject0 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libblas3gf
  libboost-thread1.49.0 libbrlapi0.5 libcap2-bin libcaribou-gtk-module
  libcaribou-gtk3-module libcmis-0.2-0 libcolorblind0
  libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-collections3-java
  libcommons-compress-java libcommons-digester-java libcommons-logging-java
  libcommons-parent-java libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.1-java
  libdb5.1-java-jni libdee-1.0-4 libdiscid0 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdotconf1.0
  libespeak1 libgail-common libgdict-1.0-6 libgdict-common libgdu-gtk0
  libgeocode-glib0 libgexiv2-1 libgnome-mag2 libgrilo-0.1-0 libgtk-vnc-2.0-0
  libgupnp-av-1.0-2 libgupnp-dlna-1.0-2 libgvnc-1.0-0 libicc2 libicu4j-java
  libimdi0 libjline-java libjtidy-java liblinear-tools liblinear1
  liblouis-data liblouis2 liblucene2-java libmagick++5 libminiupnpc5
  libmozjs17d libnatpmp1 libopencv-core2.3 libopencv-imgproc2.3 libpam-cap
  libplot2c2 libpstoedit0c2a libraw5 libregexp-java librhythmbox-core6
  libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 libsofia-sip-ua0 libsonic0 libspeechd2 libsvm-tools
  libtbb2 libtelepathy-farstream2 libunique-3.0-0 libvisio-0.0-0
  libwnck-common libwnck22 libxcb-xfixes0 libxz-java lightsoff mahjongg
  minissdpd mobile-broadband-provider-info nautilus-sendto-empathy
  network-manager-gnome nmap p7zip-full perlmagick pstoedit python-brlapi
  python-louis python-mako python-markupsafe python-pyatspi python-pyatspi2
  python-speechd python-wnck python-zeitgeist quadrapassel rdesktop rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins rygel
  rygel-playbin rygel-preferences rygel-tracker shotwell shotwell-common
  simple-scan sound-juicer sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher
  swell-foop telepathy-gabble telepathy-idle telepathy-logger telepathy-rakia
  telepathy-salut transmission-common transmission-gtk vinagre vino xbrlapi
  xdg-user-dirs-gtk xulrunner-17.0 zeitgeist-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 203 to remove and 213 not upgraded.
After this operation, 494 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
#
```

Then I ran `aptitude unmarkauto` on a subset of them that I wanted to keep.  This caused two things to happen:  First, the `aptitude` command wanted to remove the packages listed above:

```
# aptitude unmarkauto argyll baobab browser-plugin-gnash fonts-cantarell gdm3
    gnash gnash-common gnome-color-manager gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer
    gnome-nettool gnome-packagekit gnome-packagekit-data gnome-screenshot
    gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool gucharmap hamster-applet hyphen-en-us
    inkscape iputils-tracepath pstoedit
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot{u} ant{u} ant-optional{u} argyll{u} at-spi2-core{u} baobab{u}
  browser-plugin-gnash{u} caribou{u} caribou-antler{u} cheese{u}
  dconf-tools{u} empathy{u} empathy-common{u} espeak-data{u} file-roller{u}
  fonts-cantarell{u} gcalctool{u} gcr{u} gdebi{u} gdm3{u} gedit{u}
  gedit-common{u} gedit-plugins{u} gir1.2-atspi-2.0{u} gir1.2-gdata-0.0{u}
  gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0{u} gir1.2-goa-1.0{u} gir1.2-gtop-2.0{u}
  gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90{u} gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0{u} gir1.2-rb-3.0{u}
  gir1.2-tracker-0.14{u} gir1.2-webkit-3.0{u} gir1.2-wnck-3.0{u} glchess{u}
  glines{u} gnash{u} gnash-common{u} gnect{u} gnibbles{u} gnobots2{u}
  gnome-backgrounds{u} gnome-color-manager{u} gnome-disk-utility{u}
  gnome-documents{u} gnome-font-viewer{u} gnome-games{u}
  gnome-games-data{u} gnome-games-extra-data{u} gnome-icon-theme-extras{u}
  gnome-mag{u} gnome-nettool{u} gnome-orca{u} gnome-packagekit{u}
  gnome-packagekit-data{u} gnome-screenshot{u} gnome-shell-extensions{u}
  gnome-sudoku{u} gnome-system-log{u} gnome-tweak-tool{u}
  gnome-video-effects{u} gnomine{u} gnotravex{u} gnotski{u} gnuchess{u}
  gnuchess-book{u} grilo-plugins-0.1{u} gtali{u} gucharmap{u}
  guile-2.0-libs{u} hamster-applet{u} hyphen-en-us{u} iagno{u} inkscape{u}
  iputils-tracepath{u} libapache-pom-java{u} libatk-adaptor{u}
  libatk-adaptor-data{u} libatk-bridge2.0-0{u} libatspi1.0-0{u}
  libatspi2.0-0{u} libavahi-gobject0{u} libavahi-ui-gtk3-0{u} libblas3gf{u}
  libboost-thread1.49.0{u} libbrlapi0.5{u} libcap2-bin{u}
  libcaribou-gtk-module{u} libcaribou-gtk3-module{u} libcmis-0.2-0{u}
  libcolorblind0{u} libcommons-beanutils-java{u}
  libcommons-collections3-java{u} libcommons-compress-java{u}
  libcommons-digester-java{u} libcommons-logging-java{u}
  libcommons-parent-java{u} libdb-java{u} libdb-je-java{u} libdb5.1-java{u}
  libdb5.1-java-jni{u} libdee-1.0-4{u} libdiscid0{u}
  libdmapsharing-3.0-2{u} libdotconf1.0{u} libespeak1{u}
  libfolks-telepathy25{u} libgail-common{u} libgdict-1.0-6{u}
  libgdict-common{u} libgdu-gtk0{u} libgeocode-glib0{u} libgexiv2-1{u}
  libgnome-mag2{u} libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0{u} libgrilo-0.1-0{u}
  libgtk-vnc-2.0-0{u} libgupnp-av-1.0-2{u} libgupnp-dlna-1.0-2{u}
  libgvnc-1.0-0{u} libicc2{u} libicu4j-java{u} libimdi0{u} libjline-java{u}
  libjtidy-java{u} liblinear-tools{u} liblinear1{u} liblouis-data{u}
  liblouis2{u} liblucene2-java{u} libmagick++5{u} libminiupnpc5{u}
  libmozjs17d{u} libnatpmp1{u} libopencv-core2.3{u} libopencv-imgproc2.3{u}
  libpam-cap{u} libplot2c2{u} libpstoedit0c2a{u} libraw5{u}
  libregexp-java{u} librhythmbox-core6{u} libsofia-sip-ua-glib3{u}
  libsofia-sip-ua0{u} libsonic0{u} libspeechd2{u} libsvm-tools{u}
  libtbb2{u} libtelepathy-farstream2{u} libunique-3.0-0{u}
  libvisio-0.0-0{u} libwnck-common{u} libwnck22{u} libxcb-xfixes0{u}
  libxz-java{u} lightsoff{u} mahjongg{u} minissdpd{u}
  mobile-broadband-provider-info{u} nautilus-sendto-empathy{u}
  network-manager-gnome{u} nmap{u} p7zip-full{u} perlmagick{u} pstoedit{u}
  python-brlapi{u} python-louis{u} python-mako{u} python-markupsafe{u}
  python-pyatspi{u} python-pyatspi2{u} python-speechd{u} python-wnck{u}
  python-zeitgeist{u} quadrapassel{u} rdesktop{u} rhythmbox{u}
  rhythmbox-data{u} rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder{u} rhythmbox-plugins{u}
  rygel{u} rygel-playbin{u} rygel-preferences{u} rygel-tracker{u}
  shotwell{u} shotwell-common{u} simple-scan{u} sound-juicer{u}
  sound-theme-freedesktop{u} speech-dispatcher{u} swell-foop{u}
  telepathy-gabble{u} telepathy-idle{u} telepathy-logger{u}
  telepathy-rakia{u} telepathy-salut{u} transmission-common{u}
  transmission-gtk{u} vinagre{u} vino{u} xbrlapi{u} xdg-user-dirs-gtk{u}
  xulrunner-17.0{u} zeitgeist-core{u}
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 204 to remove and 213 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 493 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n
Abort.
#
```

Second, all those packages are also now marked as being manually installed (rather than just the subset that I asked for):

```
# aptitude show <all-pkgs-originally-listed-by-aptget-autoremove> | grep ^Automatically | uniq
Automatically installed: no
#
```

What is going on here?  What did `aptitude unmarkauto` do?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `aptitude unmarkauto` does not actually remove the 'pending for deletion' flag. Instead, I use `aptitude install <pkg>` to mark it as manually installed and remove it from the list of to be deleted packages.